# Splitting a string using Regex in Java

Tags: java, regex

Would anyone be able to assist me with some regex.

I want to split the following string into a number, string number

`"810LN15"`

1 method requires 810 to be returned, another requires LN and another should return 15.

The only real solution to this is using regex as the numbers will grow in length

What regex can I used to accomodate this?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you want to split on "LN", or on any alphabetic sequence?

Comment: Hi Laurent. In different methods i need to get a different part of this string, 1 method requires 810 to be returned, another requires LN and the last requires 15. I dont want to go down the route of using substrings and string counts as the lengths of the numbers are liable to change. Your help is much appreciated with this

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`String.split` won't give you the desired result, which I guess would be "810", "LN", "15", since it would have to look for a token to split at and would strip that token.

Try `Pattern` and `Matcher` instead, using this regex: `(\d+)|([a-zA-Z]+)`, which would match any sequence of numbers and letters and get distinct number/text groups (i.e. "AA810LN15QQ12345" would result in the groups "AA", "810", "LN", "15", "QQ" and "12345").

Example:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)|([a-zA-Z]+)");
Matcher m = p.matcher("810LN15");
List<String> tokens = new LinkedList<String>();
while(m.find())
{
  String token = m.group( 1 ); //group 0 is always the entire match   
  tokens.add(token);
}
//now iterate through 'tokens' and check whether you have a number or text
```

Comment: Hi Thomas, many thanks for your input, my problem is now solved

Answer (score 10):

In Java, as in most regex flavors (Python being a notable exception), the `split()` regex isn't required to *consume* any characters when it finds a match.  Here I've used lookaheads and lookbehinds to match any position that has a digit one side of it and a non-digit on the other:

```
String source = "810LN15";
String[] parts = source.split("(?<=\\d)(?=\\D)|(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts));
```

output:

```
[810, LN, 15]
```

Answer (score 7):

`(\\d+)([a-zA-Z]+)(\\d+)` should do the trick.  The first capture group will be the first number, the second capture group will be the letters in between and the third capture group will be the second number.  The double backslashes are for java.

Comment: Thanks very much for your input Mark, it helped me solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

This gives you the exact thing you guys are looking for

```
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(([a-zA-Z]+)|(\\d+))|((\\d+)|([a-zA-Z]+))");
        Matcher m = p.matcher("810LN15");
        List<Object> tokens = new LinkedList<Object>();
        while(m.find())
        {
          String token = m.group( 1 ); 
          tokens.add(token);
        }
        System.out.println(tokens);
```