# Split a infix String to an array of String in java

Tags: java, string, postfix-operator, infix-operator

I am working on a mini scientific calculator which works on `infix` to `postfix` algorithm. My input is an infix string .. and my `infix` to `postfix` conversion logic requires an `array` of `string`. So how can i split an infix string like this:

```
 100+(0.03*55)/45-(25+55)
```

To an array of String in which each operand and operator is an array element. like this

```
 "100" , "+" , "(" , "0.03" , "*" , "55" , ")" , "/" , "45" , "-"
```

and so on...

Note that there is no space in the string so it can't be split on the basis of regex `" "`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use regex for parsing a mathamatical expression stored in a string.

```
expString.split("(?<=[-+*/\\(\\)])|(?=[-+*/\\(\\)])");
```

will do the trick for you.

Say,

```
String str = "100+(0.03*55)/45-(25+55)";
String[] outs = str.split("(?<=[-+*/\\(\\)])|(?=[-+*/\\(\\)])");
for (String element : outs)
{
    System.out.println(element);
}
```

Will give you an output of,

```
100
+
(
0.03
*
55
)
/
45
-
(
25
+
55
)
```

Please check my experiment @ http://rextester.com/QEMOYL38160

Comment: The output is not correct, [100, +, (0.03, *, 55), /, 45, -, (25, +, 55)]

Answer (score 2):

Apparently each character is an apart token, except for consecutive digits with possibly a dot. So a simple solution would be iterating over the string, and then when you see a digit that is preceded by another digit (or the decimal separator, a dot), you add the character to the previous token, otherwise add it to a new token.

Here the code:

```
public static List<String> getTokens(String inputString) {
    List<String> tokens = new ArrayList<String>();
    // Add the first character to a new token. We make the assumption
    // that the string is not empty.
    tokens.add(Character.toString(inputString.charAt(0)));

    // Now iterate over the rest of the characters from the input string.
    for (int i = 1; i < inputString.length(); i++) {
        char ch = inputString.charAt(i); // Store the current character.
        char lch = inputString.charAt(i - 1); // Store the last character.

        // We're checking if the last character is either a digit or the
        // dot, AND if the current character is either a digit or a dot.
        if ((Character.isDigit(ch) || ch == '.') && (Character.isDigit(lch) || lch == '.')) {
            // If so, add the current character to the last token.
            int lastIndex = (tokens.size() - 1);
            tokens.set(lastIndex, tokens.get(lastIndex) + ch);
        }
        else {
            // Otherwise, add the current character to a new token.
            tokens.add(Character.toString(ch));
        }
    }
    return tokens;
}
```

Note that **this method is faster than most regular expression methods**.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an algorithm I would use:

start with an empty string array, and an empty string buffer

- walk from character 0 to character n
- for current character determine type (digit/period, open paren, close paren, math operators)
- if current character type is same as last character type
- add current character to buffer
- if not same, then put buffer into array of string, and start a new buffer

Answer (score 1):

You need to use lookahead and look behind with split.

This works. Ofcourse, improve regex, if you want to include more elements.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "100+(0.03*55)/45-(25+55)";
    String test[] = input.split("((?<=[\\+\\-\\*\\/\\(\\)\\{\\}\\[\\]])|(?=[\\+\\-\\*\\/\\(\\)\\{\\}\\[\\]]))");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(test));
}
```

Update :

`((?<=[a-z]])` , means it will split based on any character and include the character in the splited array as well after element.

`(?=[a-z])` , means it will split based on any character and include the character in splited array before each element.

`|` , is the or operator between two regex.

`[\\+\\-\\*\\/\\(\\)\\{\\}\\[\\]])` , is the regex to match to possible combinations

Comment: can you please explain how it works, or can you give me the link where i can study how this split function is working??? i have used split function with simple regex but not like that,

Comment: @AfzalAshraf Updated

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the answers to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5582142/splitting-a-string-using-regex-in-java).

This should do the trick:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?:(\\d+)|([+-*/\\(\\)]))");
Matcher m = p.matcher("100+(0.03*55)/45-(25+55)");
List<String> tokens = new LinkedList<String>();
while(m.find())
{
  String token = m.group( 0 ); //group 0 is always the entire match   
  tokens.add(token);
}
```

Comment: With the regex `(?:(\\d+)|([+-*/\\(\\)])` the outermost group is not captured, so it starts at group `0`. Might improve performance.