# Want to print string contains 3 letters followed by 7 digits

Tags: java, android

I am having an String like this

```
"ATS0657882\nPRX1686559\n name: something,hello"
```

Now i want to do is only get the "ATS0657882","PRX1686559", and so on,

How can i do this, i used lot of ways but i cant find the solution.

Comment: *i used lot of ways but i cant find the solution* - please share them with us. Also don't forget to tell us what didn't work with these solutions and include any error with the full stack trace.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split a string in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5582142/splitting-a-string-using-regex-in-java

Comment: @Rohit5k2 i searched but i cant find so if u could please add some example

Comment: i tried all stack overflow example for more than 1 hour

Comment: Your question headline and description doesn't match. Do you want to split by "\n" or get all the string which has three characters followed by 7 digits?

Comment: not need to get only "PRX1686559" patterns it output

Comment: @Rohit5k2 /n not matters

Comment: A regular expression like `[A-Z]{3}\\d{7}`? Matcher, find, group. It’s described in a lot of places, so just search for the details. You may want to require a word boundary before and after, search for that too.

Comment: your title says `Want to print string contains 3 letters followed by 7 digits`?  And you're asking how to split a string? you may read this guideline - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @user8478480 You may want to tell us whether you mean the question or the comments, and maybe even suggest an improvement? :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
String example = "ATS0657882\nPRX1686559\n name: something,hello";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{7}"); // or [A-Z]{3}\\d{7}
Matcher m = p.matcher(example);

while (m.find()) {
    Log.i("Findings", "values are " + m.group());
}
```

Comment: You are rocked thanks a lot :)