# Reading Polynomials from Input File (in Java)

Tags: java, file

I need to read a polynomial from a file. The problem I am facing is if the coefficients were more than one digit or if it had a negative sign, I don't know how to make the program recognize multiple digits are a single integer. That is going to really complicate my code when doing it manually since I need to make the program "aware" of its surrounding like when to start and stop. So, are there any in-built libraries that can be used to parse this? (While I was researching, I found Pattern and Matcher classes but not really sure if it can be used in this context).

For example, I know how to code for this 2x^2 + 4x + 8 but not for something like -22x^2 - 652x + 898.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are on the right trail using Pattern and Matcher Class. I found this post: [Splitting a string using Regex in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5582142/splitting-a-string-using-regex-in-java)

I am not completely sure what you are looking to do with this, or what the file looks like exactly, but pivoting off the above post you could do something like:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Polynomial
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        final String poly = "-2123x^-232-22x^2-652x+898";
        // Does not handle a missing + or - on the first term
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([-+]\\d+)x?[\\^]?([-]?\\d+)?");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(poly);
        while (m.find())
        {
            System.out.println("Entire match:" + m.group(0));
            // Showing option of casting to Integer
            System.out.println("Coefficient:" + Integer.parseInt(m.group(1)));
            // Possibly null since the last few parts don't have exponent or x
            if (null != m.group(2))
            {
                System.out.println("Exponent:" + m.group(2));
            }

        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! it works. I have one question: Is there a way to make the regex accommodate for x^1 (ex. program recognizes 2x has a exponent: 1)?

Comment: I don't think there is an easy way to do that within the regex, but within the Java body if m.group(2) is null, you would know that you're at either the x term or the constant. You could use another regex, or just check m.group(0) for x to determine down further. Or do more work with the regex.